# Why wordpress instance has stopped working properly after installing lets encrypt ssl using nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ssl

After installing let's encrypt via certbot my  wordpress website has stopped loading css/js properly. It always returns `Blocked loading mixed active content`. If I change `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` in WP admin panel website server returns `too many redirections` error.

Here are some details.

My Nginx Config

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/vergisistemi.az/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/vergisistemi.az/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Here is what `docker ps` returns:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                PORTS                                   NAMES
571d2d2c7e12   wordpress:latest     0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp   wordpress
265b6e159bc2   mysql:5.7            3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                     mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

After a half day in a searching for solution I figured out that some minor changes need to be made:

1st - adding `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` to `wp-config.php` file;

2nd - adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` to `location` in nginx config file:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
```

And voilà! Everything works smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to the top of wp-config.php did the trick for me:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: Who did the guiding? Which post or comment are you thanking for?

Comment: Also found on the WordPress Stackexchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250254